# Why not use a live packaging server for production? React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Why not use a live packaging server for production instead of making a static bundle? Wouldn't it be beneficial to have it live because you can change it whenever without resubmitting the app? Of course, the downside is that you can't access it offline, but why don't solve it by caching a bundle and fetching new only when available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to load the javascript bundle from a server, just as you describe. I'm not sure what source you are referring to when you say "why not use...", but I would imagine the reason this isn't recommended to everyone is that it wouldn't be quite as trivial as you presume:

- How do you cache the bundle?
- What happens when the package download fails?
- What if the native executable is not compatible with the loaded script code because of some native dependencies have changed?
- How do you handle hot loading new scripts to an already running application?

The point is that all these problems are possible to solve, but they do not just work out of the box, so you need to build the infrastructure to make it happen. There is also a product called [AppHub](https://apphub.io/) (apparently yet not launched), that promises to do this all for you.

Another compelling reason is Apple's app store review policies. Apple has recently explicitly allowed apps to download and execute scripts, with the following provision ([see section 3.3.2](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/information/iOS_Program_Information_4_3_15.pdf))

> provided that such scripts and code do not change
>   the primary purpose of the Application by providing features or functionality that are inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application as
>   submitted to the App Store.

However, among many developers there is quite a bit of uncertainty and suspicion whether Apple will continue to allow this, since it is so opposite to their previous review policies.

Comment: Thanks! Very detailed! Going to check AppHub out, sounds promising!